# Facing `ReferenceError` When Adding Google Fonts to Tailwind in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I want a custom font where when writing I don't need to define it one by one. How to do that? I've followed the documentation from NextJS but I'm getting the following error code like this:

> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[13].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[13].use[2]!./src/styles/globals.css
> ReferenceError: fontFamily is not defined

**_app.js**

```
import { Roboto } from "next/font/google";

const roboto = Roboto({
  weight: ["300", "400", "500", "700"],
  style: ["normal", "italic"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main className={`${roboto.variable} font-sans`}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["var(--font-roboto)", ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**globals.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume everything was done according to the documentation, except for the variable field. You should add the 'variable' field.

[image]

You are getting an error because you are trying to set 'roboto. variable' as a className, but there is no 'variable' field.

here is the example from Next.js docs